# Change jQuery UI Autocomplete Position - Pop up, instead of down

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am placing an autocomplete box at the bottom of my page and I would like the results to pop up OVER the text box, instead of below.  How can I do this?

Comment: Also refer to a very similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/9603998

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems as if I've been able to answer my own question already.  I'm open to a better solution if someones got it.  I added this to the autocomplete start up.. essentially it repositions the box on open to a new offset.

```
open: function(event, ui) {
    var autocomplete = $(".ui-autocomplete");
    var oldTop = autocomplete.offset().top;
    var newTop = oldTop - autocomplete.height() - $("#quick_add").height() - 10;

    autocomplete.css("top", newTop);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `event` and `ui` arguments if it's not used in the function. Also, it doesn't work if you resize your window. You can use F12 dev tools to test it.

Comment: Finally, I found what I need

Answer (score 33):

Putting @mvonlintel's answer in another way, set the suggestions menu position in the widget declaration:

```
$('selector').autocomplete(
{
    position: { my: "left bottom", at: "left top", collision: "flip" },
    .
    .
});
```

Comment: Nice; thanks. Excellent option for when Chrome breaks critical form element functionality by ignoring anything you tell it about not using its own autocomplete.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the jQuery UI [Position utility](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/).  Here is an example:

```
$(".ui-autocomplete").position({
    my: "left bottom",
    at: "left top",
    of: $("#quick_add"),
    collision: "flip flip"
});
```

Comment: What is `$("#quick_add")` in this example?  Is it the autocomplete box or something else?

Answer (score 5):

current version of jQuery UI allows giving the Autocomplete widget a position object with the options, with the same properties as the Position widget mentioned above. so you can use that to position the suggestions list as you like.

Comment: I agree .. best to give it as option