# Autocomplete panel position detection

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, position, panel

I am using Autocomplete plug-in of jQuery-ui, but now I would like to add position detection into this plug-in.

The idea is when the space between bottom of browser and textbox is less to display panel, the Autocomplete will auto display on the above of textbox, the default position is usually below textbox.

In the autocomplete function, there is a attribute can be set position of panel, but it is unable to be called due to it is a attribute.

```
This is default configuration, the panel will be displayed below textbox. 
$("#aaa").autocomplete({
    position:{my:"left top", at:"left bottom"}
})
```

then I changed it as following code, then the panel will be displayed above the textbox

```
$("#aaa").autocomplete({
    position:{my:"left bottom", at:"left top"}
})
```

I can already detect the space below the textbox is less than a value we set, but have no idea how to implement the idea into code.

Thanks

Comment: You can just use collision detection - `position: {  collision: "flip"  }`, more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603998/jquery-ui-autocomplete-position

Comment: you are awesome, I miss that key word..thank you so much