# How to show jquery autocomplete list upward direction

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

How to show jquery autocomplete list upward direction when it will appear at the bottom most row of any grid with a text input inside the cell.

Comment: duplicate question :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728607/change-jquery-ui-autocomplete-position-pop-up-instead-of-down

Comment: check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728607/change-jquery-ui-autocomplete-position-pop-up-instead-of-down

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the [position](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-position) option:

```
$("#yourInput").autocomplete({
    position: {
        my: "left bottom",
        at: "left top"
    }
});
```